# Which app layout is there supported in windows phone app?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, uwp

Which app layout is there supported in windows phone app? On windows phone is Pivot, but it not cool now. Modern app, Facebook, Spotify use icon panel to switch page only.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigation-basics) article about possible app layouts and guidance on what to choose and when.

Usually, the official documentation should have really good guidance on these kind of questions.